# Function curve does not touch the x-axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

There is a gap between the function I drew and the x-axis, how can I close it?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.26mm]
  \begin{axis}
    [
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={very thick},
    axis on top,
    tick style={black, thick,major tick length=6pt},
    xlabel = {$x$},
    ylabel = {$y$},
    xmin=-1, xmax=10,
    ymin=-1, ymax=1.5,
    xtick={1/2*pi,pi,3/2*pi,2*pi,5/2*pi},
    xticklabels={$\frac{\pi}{2}$,$\pi$,$\frac{3\pi}{2}$,$2\pi$,$\frac{5\pi}{2}$},
    ytick={-1,1},
    yticklabels={-1,1},
    enlargelimits={abs=0.2}
    ]
    \addplot[domain=0:5/2*pi,samples=50,smooth,very thick,red] {abs(cos(deg(x)))};
    \node at (2.5, 1.2) {$y=|cos(x)|$};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Increase the samples. `samples=50` to for `samples=200`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- remove `smooth` option

**Edit:**

- make number of samples such, that last digit is "1", for example 51, 61, 101, etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.26mm]
  \begin{axis}
    [
    trig format plots=rad,
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={very thick},
    axis on top,
    tick style={black, thick,major tick length=6pt},
    xlabel = {$x$},
    ylabel = {$y$},
    xmin=-1, xmax=10,
    ymin=-1, ymax=1.5,
    xtick={1/2*pi,pi,3/2*pi,2*pi,5/2*pi},
    xticklabels={$\frac{\pi}{2}$,$\pi$,$\frac{3\pi}{2}$,$2\pi$,$\frac{5\pi}{2}$},
    ytick={-1,1},
    yticklabels={-1,1},
    enlargelimits={abs=0.2}
    ]
    \addplot[domain=0:5/2*pi,samples=51,very thick,red] {abs(cos(x))};
    \node at (2.5, 1.2) {$y=|cos(x)|$};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In case, when in above MWE are changed axis line and tick style to:

```
    axis line style={very thin},
    tick style={very thin},
```

and set `addplot` as

```
\addplot[domain=0:5/2*pi,samples=51,red] {abs(cos(x))};
```

The result nearby `$\pi/2$` is

[image]

However to have smoother curve at maximus of functions, bigger number of samples are needed, for example 101, or 201, etc.

But if you only increase number of samples (such that they not end with 1) the result is les accurte. For example, at 200 samples you will get the following result:

[image]

So, it can be concluded, that the most important is, that the samples point and function zero values are aligned.

Comment: And additionnaly, I'd add more samples to make the curve smoother: `\addplot[domain=0:5/2*pi,samples=201...`

Comment: Neither `smooth`, nor `thickness` does have a real effect on the issue. Also the odd number `51` (every number with an 1 at the end seem to work) only solves the problem via luck. `Sample=53` for example produces the issue again. So increasing the sample number (>=200) is the only real action to take to smoothen the curve enough so that the gap is no longer visible.

Comment: @Roland, I didn't suggest that defining `thicknes` will help to solve the problem, about odd numbers, you are right. not any odd numbers but one ending wit digit 1, however, bigger is number of samples, better (smoother)  is resulted diagram of functions. See edited answer.